# Cortex M0+ MSP/PSP Context Switching

Tags: assembly, arm, stack, cortex-m, context-switch

I am using a NXP S32K118 Cortex M0+ processor

I have a "scheduler" function used to call different tasks and i need to do the following:

- Use the main stack pointer (MSP) for this "scheduler" function
- Use the process stack pointer (PSP) for a list of scheduled tasks, that are called from this scheduler function.

I have 3 stacks defined in ram ( main stack, secondary stack 1, secondary stack 2 ). The idea is that the scheduler function uses the main stack, and the scheduled tasks that are called from here use the secondary stack 1 or secondary stack 2, so i need to switch from MSP to PSP when i´m in the scheduer, before calling the corresponding task, and switch back from PSP to MSP once the corresponding task is completed and im back on the scheduler.

I know how to do the switch of these pointers writing to PSP/MSP/CONTROL registers, but the problem I have is i dont know how to do this context switch / what i need to do in addition of simply changing stack pointers in order to keep all the stacks working properly, so im here just finding for any help/tips if anyone knows how to implement this properly.

Answer (score 1):

The arrangement you describe is a little odd.  In general a "scheduler function" (context switch) does not *call* anything, but instead arranges to *return* into the appropriate task.  Unless you're writing a run-to-completion kernel, but if you are there is no need for separate stacks because everything nests.

Assuming you're aiming for preemption, *by far* the easiest way of switching stack pointers is to allow the hardware to do it for you.  Remember, either `MSP` or `PSP` is always mirrored through `r13 (sp)`.  Handler mode always uses `MSP`, so if you configure thread mode to use `PSP` using the CONTROL register (remember to do this from thread mode, before you remove thread mode privilege, and to only do it once you've got `PSP` pointing to a stack, and use a data barrier).  Now all you have to do is to ensure that your context switch runs in handler mode.  Your context switch will use `MSP`, and can swap out the active task stack in `PSP` before returning.  When it returns, it will branch to the stacked program counter value (see [the Cortex-M reference manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0497/a/the-cortex-m0-processor/exception-model/exception-entry-and-return)) so by manipulating this value you can force return to the appropriate task.